# How do I mount a Ubuntu initrd.img?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04, initrd

There is a bug with Ubuntu 10.04 Kernel updates (-31,-32) and I want to mount the initrd.img so I can compare the kernel images and see which modules are missing.

I have already tried -o loop with no success.  Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initrd (technically initramfs) is a compressed CPIO archive. You can use the `cpio` command to manipulate it.

For example: `zcat initramfs|cpio -tiv` will list the files in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

For recent Ubuntu version (22.04 in my case), `initrd.img` is compressed using LZ4 algorithm. I have to run `lz4cat initrd.img  | cpio -tiv`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).